# How can i use both: map & array in [ngClass] in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-class

How can i use both: map & array in [ngClass] in angular 4?

For example:

```
[ngClass]="[{'some-class':whenAppears()}, someReturnedClass()]"
```

where someReturnedClass is:

```
someReturnedClass() {
  return 'someClassName'
}
```

i tried so: `[ngClass]="[{'some-class':whenAppears()}, someReturnedClass()]"`

and `[ngClass]="[{'some-class':whenAppears()}]" class="someReturnedClass()"`

and `[ngClass]="{'some-class':whenAppears(), '{{someReturnedClass()}}':true}"`

but first - gives me errors, second replaces classes, third won't work too :(

how to combine without changing current logic?

Comment: <div ng-class="{'some-class':whenAppears(),someReturnedClass()}"> Dummy Data </div>

Comment: @selvassn that's wrong

Answer (score 1):

you can use the below syntax.

```
[ngClass]="[whenAppears() ? 'some-class': '', someReturnedClass()]"
```

**[Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/AuCHYXbozllKWaJi8xQK?p=preview)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div [ngClass]="someReturnedClass()" [class.some-class]="whenAppears()" ></div>
```